# how to create array for cart with session id variable after adding item into cart and display list of cart array items and Update the quantity

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, session-variables

I am working with a cart item where user can add multiple item into the cart and update or delete the item from cart. i assign selection_id in addition of every newly added one item. i am increment id one by one on each add new item into cart the code is working is fine.

i show you my cart code here. when i click add item to cart this below code has execute.

```
   if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        }
    $no_of_itm_in_cart= count($_SESSION[cart]);

    //$sl_id is Selction Id

    $sl_id=$no_of_itm_in_cart+1;
    $item_sl = array();
        $item_sl['item_sl_id']= $sl_id;
        $item_sl['item_id']=$pid;
        $item_sl['item_qty']  =$quantity;

     $_SESSION['cart'][$sl_id] = $item_sl;
```

Please share me, how to display each element and how to update and remove any element where "item_id" is a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<table>
         <tr>
            <th>SL ID</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
         </tr>';
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $row){

    echo ' <tr>
            <td>'.$row['item_sl_id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['item_id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['item_qty'].'/td>
            <td>
                 <button class="remove" data-id="'.$row['item_sl_id'].'">Remove</button>
                 <button class="edit" data-id="'.$row['item_sl_id'].'">Edit</button>
            </td>
         </tr>';
}
     echo '</table>';
```

JS.

```
$('.delete').click(function(e){
    id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url         : 'path/to/delete.php',
        type        : 'POST',
        data        : {'id':id},
        timeout     : 30000,
        success: function(e) {}
    });
});
```

delete.php

```
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]);die;
```

Comment: This is very useful for me but show me how to update and remove any element for any specified "item_id"